# Proof that arbitrary intersection of compact sets is non empty

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why the last step implies the conclusion. And also, isn't this theorem suppose to be the metric space version of the nested interval theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step the author used the fact that $S_{\lambda_0}$ is compact to deduce that we only need finitely many complements $S_{\lambda}^c$ to cover $S_{\lambda_0}$. But that means that $S_{\lambda_0}$ is in the complement of the finite intersection of these $S_{\lambda_i}$, and therefore the intersection

$S_{\lambda_0} \cap \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n S_{\lambda_i} \right)$

is empty, contradicting the assumption made in the beginning that all finite intersections of elements $S_{\lambda}$, $\lambda\in \Lambda$ is nonempty.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone is looking for a reference of the Theorem in the original question, this is Theorem 2.6 in Rudin's [Real and Complex Analysis](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf) (3rd ed.), or Proposition 4.21 in Folland's [Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160) (2nd ed.).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).